# How to not show habits in global todo list in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

The agenda view helpfully only shows habits for the current day, but habits that should not yet be done still show up in the global todo list. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

The global todo list is *global*, meaning that it lists *all* matching entries. Unfortunately, habit entries require `TODO` to be present in its headings, thus they will show up in the global todo list by default.

You can filter the global list by `tags`, `categories`, `efforts`, or `regexp` but these will not work with habits, because a habit entry is just an ordinary entry with a property `STYLE` set to `habit`.

You can, however, a) tag all your habit entry, say, `:habit:` or b) use `#+CATEGORY: habit` to filter out.  See "[10.4.4 Filtering/limiting agenda items](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items)" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since habits are scheduled, you can just do this: `(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled 'all)` and now they should be hidden. There are also a few other options like this to filter for different things:

```
org-agenda-todo-ignore-deadlines
org-agenda-todo-ignore-timestamp
org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date
org-agenda-tags-todo-honor-ignore-options
```